# Show that $A=\phi$ if primes $x,y$ are in $A \implies xy+4 \in A$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

**Question:**

> Let $A$ be a set of primes such that $x,y$ are in $A$ implies $xy+4$ is also in $A$. Prove that $A=\varnothing$

**My attempt:**

1. Let primes $x,y \in A \implies xy+4\in A\implies x(xy+4)+4,y(xy+4)+4\in A$
   $\implies x^2y+4(x+1),xy^2+4(y+1)\in A \implies ...$. I find this to be an endless cycle which would never end in a composite number. How to go about further?
2. And what about the case when $A=\{x\}$ i.e. just one prime element in $A$?

Comment: What is $\phi$?

Comment: It is the empty set.

Comment: @GAVD It is the null or empty set.

Comment: What is the source of this problem, please?

Comment: @GerryMyerson [Challenge and Thrill of Pre-College Mathematics, Pg. 613, Q. 38](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=SnvBeodeTDcC&q=Let+A+be+a+set+of+primes+such+that+x%2Cy+are+in+A+implies#v=snippet&q=Let%20A%20be%20a%20set%20of%20primes%20such%20that%20x%2Cy%20are%20in%20A%20implies&f=false)

Comment: If $p$ is in $A$, then $p^2+4$ must be prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Get a contradiction by showing that at some point, 7 must divide one of the numbers.
Look at what happens to remainders mod 7 under $a \to a^2+4$ and $(a,b) \to ab+4$.

Comment: So, I got that $a \equiv 1,2,3,4,5,6 (mod 7)$ and $a^2+4 \equiv 1,2,5,6 (mod 7)$ and then $(a^2+4)^2+4 \equiv 1, 5$. I don't know how to proceed further :( And I also don't get why you picked $7$ and not any other number. Please help.

Comment: So you've deduced that if $A$ is not empty then it contains a prime $p\equiv1\bmod7$ and a prime $q\equiv5\bmod7$. Then $r=pq+4\equiv2\bmod7$, and $qr+4\equiv0\bmod7$ isn't prime. My guess is Aravind tried 2, 3, and 5, and they didn't work, but then 7 did.

Comment: As Gerry Myerson says, 2,3,5 don't work. The problem is they have fixed points of $a \to a^2+4$, eg: 2 (mod 3), 3 (mod 5).

Comment: Thank you both for your help! I got the answer!